# URL passes parameter in my Django project

Tags: python, django

I am just a beginner of Django, these days I followed a mooc to learn Django, I wanted to set up my first website, but something went wrong and I can not figure out. I wanted to write a regex with parameter 'cate' in URLS.py to match the video function in my view.py, judging whether 'cate' eequals 'editors', if yes it will bring back data with attribute "editors_choice". However, I found no it never changes, so I printed 'cate' in view.py and found it always None and I still don't know why.

Following is my code:

```
def video(request, cate=None):
    print(cate)
    context = {} =
    if cate is None:
        video_list = Video.objects.all()
    if cate == 'editors':
        video_list = Video.objects.filter(editors_choices=True)
    else:
        video_list = Video.objects.all()
    page_robot = Paginator(video_list, 16)
    page_num = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        video_list = page_robot.page(page_num)
    except EmptyPage:
        video_list = page_robot.page(page_robot.num_pages)  # raise HTTP404("Empty")
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        video_list = page_robot.page(1)
    context['video_list'] = video_list
    return render(request, 'ten_movie.html', context)
```

---

[image: 'cate' parameter in urls.py]

---

[image: templete]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a regex end-of-string character to the first pattern to prevent it from overlapping with the second.

```
url(r'^video/$', video, name='video'),
url(r'^video/(?P<cate>[A-Za-z]+)$', video, name='video'),
```

Comment: I solve it by adding $ after the first url but not change the name. I still thank you very much for solving my problem within several minutes that I struggle several days.